# how to display next 30 days records , based on the input data?

Tags: mysql

From User Interface , 
user can select a date and click on the submit button ,
based on the input field how to display next 30 days records ??

This is my sqlfiddle 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1f3b/1

Currently i am using between as shown below

```
select * from historical_data
where current_day between '01-OCT-2015' and '07-OCT-2015'
```

Could you please let me know how can i write a query for this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper datatypes. Use `date` and the likes of `decimal`. Not `varchar` for these.

**Your code:**

```
create table historical_data
(
current_day varchar(50) ,
open_value varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO historical_data (current_day,open_value) values ('01-OCT-2015','23.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data (current_day,open_value) values ('03-OCT-2015','26.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data (current_day,open_value) values ('05-OCT-2015','21.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data (current_day,open_value) values ('03-Strawberries','33.44');


select * from historical_data
where current_day between '01-OCT-2015' and '07-OCT-2015'
```

**yikes, you got Strawberries**

**Instead, do:**

```
create table historical_data2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    current_day date not null ,
    open_value decimal(10,2) not null
);
truncate table historical_data2;
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-09-01','11.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-10-01','23.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-10-03','26.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-10-04','21.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('03-Strawberries','33.44'); -- Error 1292: Incorrect date value
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-10-31','22.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-11-01','33321.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-11-02','4443321.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-11-03','55533321.50');
INSERT INTO historical_data2 (current_day,open_value) values ('2015-11-04','66633321.50');
```

Harness the power of built-in mysql's [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like `add_add` and `interval` functionality. These become available when you use proper data types. Plus math is performed properly, and they consume less space.

```
select * from historical_data2 
where current_day between '2015-10-02' and DATE_ADD(date('2015-10-02'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
+----+-------------+------------+
| id | current_day | open_value |
+----+-------------+------------+
|  3 | 2015-10-03  |      26.50 |
|  4 | 2015-10-04  |      21.50 |
|  5 | 2015-10-31  |      22.50 |
|  6 | 2015-11-01  |   33321.50 |
|  7 | 2015-11-02  | 4443321.50 |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

**The takeaway:** use proper datatypes

Comment: I cannot chnage the datatype as it will be reflected in lot of places , could you please tell me so i am using date_to_str and tried this way select * from historical_data
where current_day between str_to_date('2015-10-02','%Y-%m-%d') and DATE_ADD(str_to_date('2015-10-09','%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

Comment: but why is it not returning any results ??

Comment: Preethi, all I can say is sometimes we provide an Answer that does not necessarily help the OP 100% (or if at all), but it benefits others that follow. As for your question in comments, I am sure there are many examples of that on the stack or else where.